# How do I access just the filtered rows in a range from VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to use the results of an AutoFilter method within VBA. I can apply the AutoFilter method (using a named range), but can't figure out how to create a Range variable in VBA that only includes the results. I then want to loop through this result range. I can't figure out how to do this without simply checking every row for its Visible property and acting on those rows.

```
Public Sub CopyFilteredRows()
   Dim sourceRg As Range, filteredRg As Range, objRow As Range

   Set sourceRg = ThisWorkbook.Names("FY10CountsRg").RefersToRange
   sourceRg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=D-144", Operator:=xlOr, _
     Criteria2:="=D-200"

   For Each objRow In filteredRg.Rows
      ''do something
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this - it should just hit the visible cells & print their values -  you should be able to tweak it do the job:

```
Dim rgAreas As Range: Set rgAreas = FilteredRg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Dim rgArea  As Range
Dim rgCell  As Range

For Each rgArea In rgAreas.Areas
    For Each rgCell In rgArea.Cells
        Debug.Print rgCell.Address & ": " & rgCell.Value
    Next rgCell
Next rgArea
```